# $dirty set value on focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a form in AngularJS and I want validate the fields, the problem is that the required message appear only if write something in the input and after I delete it, but I want that the message appear after to focus the input

my code is the following

```
<input type="text" name="textInput" data-ng-model="field.data"  class="form-control" required/>
<span  ng-show="form.textInput.$dirty && form.textInput.$error.required">Required!</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
<span  ng-show="form.textInput.$touched && form.textInput.$error.required">Required!</span>
```

This will show the message after you touched and left(lost focus) with the field invalid. [**Documentation**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$touched)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's doable. First add a directive like this:

```
myApp.directive('trackFocus', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: true,
        link: function ($scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            element.on("focus", function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                    ctrl.hasFocus = true;
                });
            });

            element.on("blur", function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                    ctrl.hasFocus = false;
                });
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Then use the directive and modify your code:

```
<input type="text" name="textInput" ng-model="field.data"  class="form-control" required track-focus />

<span ng-show="form.textInput.hasFocus && form.textInput.$dirty && form.textInput.$error.required">Required!</span>
```